# Difference between lengua and idioma?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

For instance, If I wanted to express the following:

> Globally, Spanish is an important **language**.

Should I use *lengua* or *idioma*, or are they interchangeable within this context?

I'm aware of a distinction in Portuguese where the former ("lingua" rather than "lengua") refers to all spoken languages whilst the latter is with reference to national languages.

Does a difference of this sort exist in Spanish?

Thanks.

Comment: Spanish for "language" is **lengua**, not "lingua" ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the DRAE, *idioma* is the *Lengua de un pueblo o nación, o común a varios*. So most *lenguas* are also *idiomas*.

The word *idioma* carries a stronger idea of structure and identity. So you would not use it in some fuzzy cases where you could not even put a name to a specific language. For instance, you may speak about the *lengua de los antiguos iberos*, which is pretty much unknown nowadays, while *idioma de los antiguos iberos* would sound weird. Or a language which is, in fact, a peculiar way of speaking, such as *lengua de germanías* (a language used among criminals and outlaws).

Another exception is the *lengua de signos* (*sign language*), which would not be *idioma de signos*. But, aside from those, the words *lengua* and *idioma* are basically interchangeable.

Comment: I forgot to mention we have an additional word: *lenguaje*, which is a bit different from *lengua* or *idioma*. Too subtle to explain in a few words, but we would say *lenguaje de programación* for *programming language*, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Lengua is more formal, as in e.g. La Real Academía de la Lengua Española. Also, lengua is used in specific expressions such as lengua materna, the biblical "hablar en lenguas/don de lenguas" and others.

There is also the word lenguaje - meaning lingo or jargon - which has no precise synonym.

In everyday speech, you would seldom if ever use the word lengua.

Answer (score 2):

**Lengua** sistema de comunicación verbal y casi siempre escrito, propio de una comunidad humana.

Puede no darse coincidencia entre comunidad lingüística y comunidad político-social, es decir que el dominio geográfico de una lengua no coincida con la extensión territorial independiente de un poder político o Estado.

En España la lengua española es el idioma oficial del Estado pero las demás lenguas peninsulares, como el catalán, el euskera, el gallego, son también idiomas oficiales en sus respectivas comunidades autónomas.

Una misma lengua puede pertenecer a varios países, como ocurre con el francés, el español o el inglés, mientras que otra lengua, como el catalán, puede hablarse en tres países y tener distinto estatus en cada uno de ellos: oficial en Andorra, cooficial en Cataluña, y sin reconocimiento expreso en Francia.

Esa facultad humana de comunicarse, presenta manifestaciones diversas según los distintos grupos humanos que existen. Cada una de las manifestaciones es una lengua.

**Idioma:** Lengua, perfectamente desarrollada,  empleada en una comunidad, particularmente cuando constituye un estado o nación: Habla cuatro idiomas.
El término ‘idioma’ se emplea con mayor frecuencia al hablar de las lenguas extranjeras, como en el enunciado “Saber idiomas es muy importante”.

Hay que observar que un idioma es siempre una lengua, pero una lengua no siempre es un idioma.

**Idioma** también es el modo particular de hablar de algunos o en algunas ocasiones. En idioma de la corte. En idioma de palacio.
Si el concepto de idioma o lengua oficial proviene de causas culturales, políticas e históricas, el concepto de dialecto presenta consideraciones únicamente lingüísticas y culturales. Porque debe entenderse como dialecto cada una de las variedades regionales de una lengua.

**Dialecto** es la forma particular en que una lengua es hablada en un determinado lugar o medio social.
Los dialectos son las variantes o modalidades regionales de una lengua. Tales variantes no afectan a la unidad del sistema.

En consecuencia, todos los dialectos de una lengua ofrecerán en sincronía un único sistema lingüístico en su estructura pero manifestarán específicas preferencias en el funcionamiento de ese sistema común. Estas preferencias se situarán en los distintos niveles, léxico, morfosintáctico y fonológico, o únicamente en alguno de ellos.

Hoy en día, en un mundo globalizado, el concepto comunidad es un tanto subjetivo y la consideración de idioma, lengua o dialecto muchas veces está politizada.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that they are pretty much interchangeable. I think that `lengua` refers to the language itself, while `idioma` has the connotation of the language being used in a place (country, region) or by certain people (like a subset of the population, e.g. Catalonians), but this might be a fuzzy differene.

As a native

> El español es una **lengua** importante.

sounds better to me, but nothing wrong with

> El español es un **idioma** importante.